# Elegant way to write multiple If statements

Tags: c++

I have the following Multiple 'if' statements.

Animals and Humans are two `enum`s.

```
Var a, b;
int c, d, e = 0;

if (a == Humans ::Men) {
    c = 1;
}

if (b == Animals ::Cat) {
    d= 1;
    e= 1;
}

if (b == Animals ::Dog) {
    d = 1;
}

if (b == Animals ::Elephant) {
    e = 1;
}
```

How can I write everything in one statement, so that the meaning is still the same.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There is no simpler way. Stuffing it all into one statement is possible, but will actively harm readability.

Comment: What is `Var`, and why do you allow assigning different types of `enum` to it? That seems ill-advised. Also, note that your declaration only assigns `0` to `e`, so you can end up in a situation where `c` and `d` are never initialised, which would be extremely bad. (I assume you really pass `a` and `b` from somewhere else rather than declaring them as empty... You should always post full, compilable code, though, rather than requiring readers to guess.)

Comment: aside:  the only variable that is 0 at the start is `e`; `c` and `d` are all uninitialised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever possible, I find that some sort of tabulation based method is the most easily extendable. I'll demonstrate with `std::map`, but you can use other sorts of bookkeeping data structures. It's simply a matter of defining a mapping from the pairs of possible enumerations values to the triplets of values you intend to assign onto the variables:

```
using from_type = std::tuple<Humans, Animals>;
using to_type   = std::tuple<int, int, int>;
std::map<from_type, to_type> value_getter {
  { from_type{Humans::Men, Animals::Cat}, to_type{0, 1, 1} },
  // etc.
};

int c, d, e;
std::tie(c, d, e) = value_getter[from_type{a, b}];
```

Or, if you feel fancy and your compiler is up to supporting C++17 properly already, you can use the same map with structured bindings:

```
auto [c, d, e] = value_getter[from_type{a, b}];
```

So now initialization is part of the declaration, and is good wholesome C++.

Answer (score 7):

You can set up your `enum` with specific values such that *masking* is possible. (`Men`, `Cat`, `Dog`, `Element` have exactly one, but unique, bit set). Bitwise enumerators with masking values are common.

Then you could write

```
if (b & Animals::d_applies){
    d = 1;
}
```

where, at the very least, `d_applies` is `Animals::Cat | Animals::Dog`

Answer (score 0):

You can arrange a container that contains pairs like "predicate, handler". Then you can iterate the container and call the handler if corresponding predicate do matches. std::for_each would be nice one-liner here after all setup code being done.

P.S. Not sure it's worth a bullet, however.